# Python syntax - cannot see why receiving syntax error

Tags: python

I'm working though a course on Python. The following code is meant to count the vowels in a string. I typed it out as I thought it should be and did not work. I then cut n paste from lecture notes and it did work.

But I cannot see what the difference is! I've commented out my non working expressions. The working expression is below it.

Why does mine not work?

```
    ## count the number of vowels in string s
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
vowelcount = 0
for char in s:
    ## if char == 'a' or char = 'e' or char == 'i' or char == 'o' \
       ## or char == 'u':

    if char == 'a' or char == 'e' or char == 'i' \
       or char == 'o' or char == 'u':

         vowelcount += 1
print "Number of vowels: " + str(vowelcount)
```

Here is the error message:

```
%run "/var/folders/cs/31zvz_q925v_z3tmvj09dpyc0000gn/T/tmpCEB9ME.py"
File "/var/folders/cs/31zvz_q925v_z3tmvj09dpyc0000gn/T/tmpCEB9ME.py", line 4
if char == 'a' or char = 'e' or char == 'i' or char == 'o' \
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Could you please post your error message?

Comment: @AnkurAnkan I have added this now

Comment: You can see that you are using a single `=` that means you are doing assignment operation rather than comparision.

Comment: I got such a big response to this question. Clearly many folk follow the Python tag and it has a strong community behind it. Thanks for the help on my syntax error I'm really glad to be picking this up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `==` instead of `=`.

I suggest using the following equivalent instead, as it’s more pythonic and more readable:

```
if char in 'aeiou':
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `==` for comparison tests:

```
if char == 'a' or char == 'e' or char == 'i' \
   or char == 'o' or char == 'u':
```

`=` is only used for variable assignment.

---

Or, even better here would be to use `in`:

```
if char.lower() in "aeiou":
```

This code tests whether a lowercase version of `char` can be found in the string `"aeiou"`.  I added `.lower()` so that your code can handle uppercase vowels.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` is pointing you to the exact error.

```
or char = 'e'
```

must be

```
or char == 'e'
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you Lutz Horn. And thanks for the tip on ^. Accepting shortly